# Laravel Redirect::to Wrong Redirect In Subdomain

Tags: php, laravel-4

```
//Backend's Route
Route::group(array('domain' => 'admin.web.com', 'before' => 'inGroup:Administrator-Operator-Editor-Reporter'), function() {
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return Redirect::action('NewsC@index');
    });
    Route::resource('news', 'NewsC');
});
```

Why when i go to 'admin.web.com' laravel redirect to **' admin.web.com/http://admin.web.com/news '** ? , it must redirect to **'admin.web.com/news'**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `return Redirect::action('NewsC@index');` please try with `return Redirect::route('news',array('params_for_your_routes'));` For more information please [check](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects) here.